# Getting Max date in Linq Query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to get maxdate in linq where clause. If i try like below, it throws an error.

```
var dt1 = dtCurTopSQL.AsEnumerable()
     .Where (l => 
        l.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME").Max() >= DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(lastxminutes))
```

Error:

> Error  CS1929  'DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'Max'

Comment: Try reading the error message.

Comment: @SLaks It just doesn't work with this syntax.

Comment: _Why not? What happens_

Comment: @SLaks Error CS1929 'DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'Max'

Comment: Indeed `DateTime` does not have `Max` - it is single value... What exactly you expect to happen in this case for example `1.Max()` ?

Comment: You need another `)` before `.Max`

Comment: @CodingYoshi didn't work.

Comment: Please elaborate what didn't work. Error? Or wrong result

Comment: @S.Doe, You still have not explained what it is you are trying to achieve `var dt1 = dtCurTopSQL.AsEnumerable().Where(l => l.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME") >= DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(lastxminutes)).Max(l => l.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME"));`

Comment: @S.Doe if it works can you upvote my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

`.Max()` only operates on a collection, not a field.

You need to calculate the maximum value first, from the entire collection:

```
var maxDate = dtCurTopSQL.Max(r => r.Whatever);
```

You can then use that variable in other queries.

Comment: Throws an error 'Datatable doesnot contain definition  for 'Max''

Comment: Ah; then you need `AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: Still same When i use liked this 'var dt1 = dtCurTopSQL.AsEnumerable()
                  .Where(l => dtCurTopSQL.Max(r => r.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME")) >= DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(lastxminutes))'

Comment: Don't re-calculate the `Max()` every time you check a row.